# While converting a list of String to map using toMap() i am getting illigleStateExcption why?

Tags: java

Below is the sample code, Suggest me what is wrong here as per my knowledge, I am passing a new key every time still it says duplicate key.

```
public class CollectorsDemo5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> listOfCities=new ArrayList<String>();

        listOfCities.add("Istanbul");
        listOfCities.add("Istanbul");
        listOfCities.add("Budapest");
        listOfCities.add("Delhi");
        listOfCities.add("Amsterdam");
        listOfCities.add("Canberra");
        listOfCities.add("Canberra");

        Map<Integer, String> map = listOfCities.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(listOfCities::indexOf, Function.identity()));

        map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("key:"+k +"  value:"+v)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There are duplicates in your list. Calling indexOf for `Istanbul` will only return 0 all the time.

Comment: You can also solve your problem by using the version of `toMap()` that takes a merge function, which allows you to explicitly decide what to do with duplicates.

Comment: I know I can solve this by using merge function. But what I am asking is that I am passing the index of the list as key, so each time it will be unique(as per my assumption), while values will be duplicate .still the toMap() function is complaining about duplicate key. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Some of list elements are duplicate.

Hence `indexOf` will return the same value -> Throw duplicate key exception.

What you can do is to do a normal `for` loop:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfCities.size(); i++) {
   map.put(i, listOfCities.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that exception because you have duplicate values in your stream. You can produce the result you desire with `IntStream`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = IntStream.range(0, listOfCities.size())
    .mapToObj(Function.identity())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), listOfCities::get));
```

Comment: Are duplicate values not allowed in Stream? Or Map cannot accept the duplicate values? However, I will like to thank you for your effort.

Comment: @saroj the collector doesn't allow duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple *for* loop would be the way to go here. If you really want to use Streams

```
IntStream.range(0, listOfCities.size())
            .collect(HashMap::new, (map, index) -> map.put(index, listOfCities.get(index)), HashMap::putAll);
```

This produces

```
{0=Istanbul, 1=Istanbul, 2=Budapest, 3=Delhi, 4=Amsterdam, 5=Canberra, 6=Canberra}
```

The above creates a new `HashMap` to which we add the city name keyed by the index. The last combiner is only applicable when using a parallel stream and is used to combine the multiple maps.

Comment: It's _a_ way to go, but I think its a more direct solution to simply provide a merge function to the `toMap()` collector.

Comment: @BrianGoetz AFAIU, the best you can do in a merge function is to pick one of them (or concat them or something like that) - but whatever you do it is for *that particular* key (index here). But I *guess* that the OP's intent is to construct a map containing values keyed by the index.

Comment: Thanks, user7 I think your answer could be a good solution to my problem